# Google Android Sales Report Auto Ingesting like iTunes Connect

Tags: android, ios, app-store-connect

I'm using the tool iTunes Connects to sales report for iOS platform applications.

http://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf

I need a tool like applications for the Android platform, but have not found any yet.

Google has a tool like iTunes Connect sales report to?

Answer (score 0):

Under each of your apps, you can click on the statistics tab to bring up information about the Android version, device, country, language, app version, and operator of your users.
[image: Screenshot]

For all your financial reports, click on the money symbol on the left hand side of the developer console to see this screen:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I need to have this information from another system.